# Is there a list/log of Windows XP setup drivers loaded during installation?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, setup

I need to know what drivers Windows XP setup loads during installation ([for another question](https://superuser.com/questions/562845/how-do-i-fix-a-windows-xp-bootloader-error-when-bootcfg-fixboot-and-fixmbr-do)), but some of the drivers' names flicker by too fast for me to read.

Is there another way of see the list of drivers that are loaded during install? This is what I've been able to glimpse (in order):

- Windows Executive
- Hardware Extraction Level
- Kernel Debugger DLL
- Windows Setup
- PCI Bus Driver
- ISA Bus Driver
- IEEE ...
- ...
- Enhanced Host Controller
- Open Host Controller
- Universal Host Controller
- Generic USB Hub Driver
- ...
- Human Interface Driver
- Video Driver
- ...